# Find and SCP file from server using bash script

Tags: bash, find, scp

Following is my bash Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "directory: $1"
echo "filename: $2"
echo "username: $3"
echo "destination: $4"
echo "host: $5"
SEARCH=$2*
echo "Search: $SEARCH"
for i in 'ssh $3@$5 find $1 -type f -name SEARCH'
do
    echo $PWD
    FILE=$i
    echo "FILE= $FILE"
    scp $3@$5:$FILE $4
done
```

Here is my output:

```
directory: **Correct Directory**
filename: **Correct Filename**
username: **Correct username**
destination: ./STORAGE
host: **Correct Host**
Search: filename*
/Users/ranjanasinha/ransinha/POS-INVESTIGATION
FILE= ssh $3@$5 find $1 -type f -name $SEARCH
scp: ssh: No such file or directory
cp: $3@$5: No such file or directory
cp: find: No such file or directory
cp: $1: No such file or directory
cp: -type: No such file or directory
cp: f: No such file or directory
cp: -name: No such file or directory
```

I'm expecting the FILE to have the found filenames. My question is why does "i" not get the found files? What is wrong with the command?

Comment: `for i in $(ssh $3@$5 find $1 -type f -name $SEARCH)`

Comment: You should quote the command properly: `for i in $(ssh $3@$5 "find '$1' -type f -name '$SEARCH'")` -- the double-quotes allow the local shell to substitute `$1` and `$SEARCH`, but then the single quotes (just passed through by the local shell) keep the remote shell from doing silly things like prematurely expanding `filename*` into a list of matching filenames in the working directory. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465980/how-to-keep-parameter-with-spaces-when-running-remote-script-file-with-ssh/53472697) for more explanation.