# Using escape characters inside double quotes in ssh command in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, escaping

I want to run some commands each time when I log in to a remote system. Storing commands in `.bashrc` on remote is not an option.

What is the proper way to escape the escape chars inside of quotes in bash script for ssh?
How can I write each command in new line?

My script

```
#!/bin/bash

remote_PS1=$'\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\[\033[03;80m\]\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\!:\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
ssh -t "$@" 'export SYSTEMD_PAGER="";' \
            'export $remote_PS1;' \
            'echo -e "set nocompatible" > /home/root/.vimrc;' \
            'bash -l;'
```

didn't work.

Comment: Use heredoc with `ssh` to avoid any escaping

Comment: You generally need two layers of quotes on commands to be sent over ssh: one to be parsed, applied, and removed by the *local* shell, and a second to be parsed, applied, and removed by the *remote* shell (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465980/how-to-keep-parameter-with-spaces-when-running-remote-script-file-with-ssh)). Also, be aware what's happening locally vs remotely; in your current script, `remote_PS1` is only defined in the local shell, not the remote one (and you shouldn't use `$` when `export`ing it).

Comment: I defined `remote_PS1` in local script but I tried to use it in third line.

Comment: Since the third line is in single-quotes, the local shell won't expand the `$variable` reference, just remove the single-quotes and pass the command on literally; the remote shell will then see it as an unquoted variable reference, try to expand it, get nothing, and therefore run the command `export ;`, which is invalid. Putting that line in double-quotes would cause a different problem; the local shell would expand the variable, and pass it to the remote shell as `export <bunchofgibberishescapes> ;` with no variable name. You have to think carefully about exactly what's happening where.

Comment: What you could use on the third line is `"export PS1='$remote_PS1';" \` -- the double-quotes will allow `$remote_PS1` to expand, but the single-quotes will protect that expanded value when it gets to the remote shell. Yes, this really is complicated (and if the value had any single-quotes in it, it'd be even more complicated). And as I suggested in the other answer, you can debug it by replacing `ssh -t "$@"` with `echo`, to see what'd be sent to the remote shell (i.e. the command after the local shell processes it, but before the remote shell does).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bash's `printf %q`.

According to `help printf`:

> `%q`      quote the argument in a way **that can be reused as shell input**

See the following example:

```
$ cat foo.sh
ps1='\[\033[1;31m\]\u:\w \[\033[0m\]\$ '
ps1_quoted=$( printf %q "$ps1" )
ssh -t foo@localhost \
    'export FOO=bar;' \
    "export PS1=$ps1_quoted;" \
    'bash --norc'
```

Result:

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1):

Escaping escape characters inside double-quotes and run them on remote server is way too complicated for me :)
Instead, I wrote a `remoterc` file for remote and a small `remotessh` script.
In `remotessh`, first I copy `remoterc` on remote machine and run `bash` command with that `remoterc` file interactively.

*remoterc*:

```
#!/bin/bash
SYSTEMD_PAGER=""
PS1="\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\[\033[03;80m\]\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\!:\w\[\033[00m\]\$ "
echo -e "set nocompatible" > /home/root/.vimrc
```

*remotessh*:

```
#!/bin/bash 
scp remoterc "$1":/home/root/ 
ssh "$1" -t "bash --rcfile remoterc -i"
```

It works :)