# How to Export variable with spaces in ssh

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, ssh, arguments

Bonjour, I'm trying to do something in bash,
here is the code :

```
var1=Hello
var2=I want a coffee
function func () {          
var_temp="alias $1='$2'"          #I need ='' in the result
echo $1
echo $2 
echo $var_temp; }
sshpass -e ssh -q $USER@host "$(declare -f func);func" $var1 $var2
```

```
Result $1=Hello
Result $2=I
Result $var_temp=alias Hello='I'
```

How can I export more than one word in ssh ?
Thank you in advance,
#be understanding for my english xD

Comment: What are you doing with the output of `func`? If you want to add something to a file, just construct the string *locally* and pipe it to something like `ssh $USER@host 'cat >> the_file'`.

Comment: Before worrying about `ssh`, get the local things fixed: `var2=I want a coffee` needs quotes or escapes to protect the spaces, and all variable references should be double-quoted (e.g. `echo "$var_temp"` instead of just `echo $var_temp`). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out missing double-quotes. As for `ssh`, my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465980/how-to-keep-parameter-with-spaces-when-running-remote-script-file-with-ssh) may help.

Comment: E.g. `printf "alias %s='%s'\n" "$var1" "$var2" | ssh ...`

Comment: WIth the output, I want to add string in a file with a sed at a specific lines "after" ``` sudo sed -i "text /a $var_alias" /etc/.....sh ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
var1=Hello
var2="I want a coffee"
func(){                     
    var_temp="alias $1='$2'"      
    echo "$1"
    echo "$2"
    echo "$var_temp"
}
sshpass -e ssh -q $USER@host "$(declare -f func);func" "'$var1'" "'$var2'"
```