# Why would I want to wrap my script commands in double quotes?

Tags: bash, shell, double-quotes, single-quotes

I'm working through Red Hat Academy and one of the sample scripts provided differed from mine in a key way that I haven't been able to understand:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#
USR='student'
OUT='/home/student/output'
#
for SRV in servera serverb
  do
ssh ${USR}@${SRV} "hostname -f" > ${OUT}-${SRV}
echo "#####" >> ${OUT}-${SRV}
ssh ${USR}@${SRV} "lscpu | grep '^CPU'" >> ${OUT}-${SRV}
echo "#####" >> ${OUT}-${SRV}
ssh ${USR}@${SRV} "grep -v '^$' /etc/selinux/config|grep -v '^#'" >> ${OUT}-${SRV}
echo "#####" >> ${OUT}-${SRV}
ssh ${USR}@${SRV} "sudo grep 'Failed password' /var/log/secure" >> ${OUT}-${SRV}
echo "#####" >> ${OUT}-${SRV}
done
```

On each line after the variable expansion, they've wrapped most of the rest of the command in double quotes.  Now, I understand the usage of double quotes and single quotes when it comes to suppressing expansion/substitution, but the main takeaway I've learned is straight from the RH Academy:

> It is recommended practice to use single quotation marks to
> encapsulate the regular expression to protect any shell metacharacters
> (such as the $, *, and {} characters). Encapsulating the regular
> expression ensures that the characters are interpreted by the intended
> command and not by the shell.

I can see that they're doing that here to make sure the regular expressions are properly passed to `grep` in a couple of lines, but I can't figure out the purpose of the double quotes.  My questions are:

- Why are they there?
- Why are they only wrapped around a portion of
  each line?
- Is this a common practice?

Comment: The important part is `ssh`. The commands are running on a remote machine. Some of them might work without the quotes, too, but you'd have to escape some characters (vertical bars, quotes, etc.).

Comment: please don't learn from it, I can already see 2 bad practices and 2 sub-optimal constructs

Comment: Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your script

Comment: @choroba So you're saying those characters have a different meaning in the context of the ssh command?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @dylosaur ssh remote command is evaluated so you need to provide a string that represents a shell script; here they double-quote it so that they can use single-quotes inside; it has its caveats but works fine in this case.

Comment: The remote command will go through two "layers" of shell parsing & quote/escape removal, first by the local shell (before the arguments are passed to `ssh`), then second by the remote shell, so you need more complex quoting than for a local command. See my answer to ["how to keep parameter with spaces when running remote script file with ssh?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465980/how-to-keep-parameter-with-spaces-when-running-remote-script-file-with-ssh/53472697)

Comment: @Gordon Davisson, as an aside, is there any possible confusion of interpretation by grep for the string **'^$'**, since that seemingly is attempting to match an empty string from both ends of the string, or is it always left-to-right interpretation, directing grep to ignore anything starting with "**$**" ?

Comment: @EricMarceau I'm not sure I understand the question. In regex syntax, `^` matches the beginning of the string (/line) *unless* it's the first character in a `[ ]` bracket expression, (in which case it negates the expression). In your commands, it's not the first character in a `[ ]` expression, so it unambiguously matches the beginning of the string, so `^$` will match zero-length strings and `^#` will match strings that start with "#".

Comment: I never consciously faced the situation before, so I wasn't sure if it would do as I had described in my comment.  Thank you for confirming that the "$" is protected by its directive status for the grep command.

Comment: @EricMarceau I wouldn't say it's protected. If you use it in a place where the shell can treat it as starting a variable substitution (`$var` or `${var}`) or command substitution (`$(command)`), or something like that, and don't properly quote or escape it to prevent that interpretation, the shell *will* treat it as a variable or whatever expansion. The shell has no idea that `grep` will treat it as a regex, so if there's anything in your regex that *can* be mistaken for shell syntax, it *will* be mistaken for shell syntax.

Comment: @GordonDavisson So it's not like **every** `$` needs to be escaped, but it's something I'll need to be aware of.  Do you personally `echo` commands being sent through `ssh` like you recommend in your linked answer?  Or is there some more widely used and robust mechanism where you can trust that the proper command is being sent to the remote host?

Comment: @dylosaur The best way to make sure the right command gets sent is the hard way: understand shell command-line processing well enough that you can predict and control what's going to happen at each step. `echo` is a useful trick for debugging & verifying (for `ssh`, not for other things). There are others; for example, I have a little Python script called `printargs` that just prints its arguments (but clearly delimited, and with normally-invisible characters visible), which I can use in place of other commands to see exactly what'll be passed to them.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others, the example provided has issues of being *malformed for the intended purpose*.  Specifically, the **3rd ssh** requires the "**$**" in **'^$'** to be escaped, to avoid the shell's attempt at substitution at your end.  Otherwise, the remote host will see **'^'** !!!

Their usage of double-quotes is intended to "**encapsulate**" a *construct meant to be executed* **as is** on the remote server, hence around everything after the target host reference.

Issues arise if you need to expand variable values **before** sending to remote ... **AND** ... when you need such expansion to **NOT** occur.  **Single-quotes** are meant to contain literals meant to be passed as-is, but if that is contained within another set of double-quotes, the contents of those are **not** "protected" and the shell attempts the usual substitutions whenever "$" is encountered.

For simple constructs, one-line commands are OK.

BUT ... when things get more complex (*with multiple levels of "\" for escaping single-/double-quotes*), it might be best to create a **job-script**, massage that into what is required for the remote host before calling ssh, then have ssh reference that in the following manner:

```
ssh user@remote 'bash -s' < local_script.sh
```

As for the line doing the check for failed password, I would never leave that to the end.  I would have that as the first line, check the output, and abandon if the password failed, avoiding the likely failed attempts for the other commands, which at that point serves no purpose.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "but if that is contained within another set of double-quotes, the contents of those are not "protected""? Aside from your job-script idea, which I feel is beyond my current skill level, I'm not sure how to check that my arguments are passed as intended, and what you've said about `ssh` seems to complicate the rules I've learned about single and double quotes.  Specifically, I don't really see why the "$" in the 3rd `ssh` command needs to be escaped.  Wouldn't the local shell remove the double quotes and send the rest (including single quotes) to the remote host?

Comment: The single-quotes will be sent.  BUT ... every "$" within double-quotes will be expanded by the LOCAL shell.  The single-quotes do **NOT** protect them because the double-quotes override the single-quotes by being the outer-most set. The only way to pass an unexpanded "$" is if they are "**escaped**" by a preceding "\".  The single-quotes are **invisible** to the shell (not interpreted by the shell) if they are between the outer double-quotes.

Comment: Ignore the fact that you are working with ssh.  Replace everything before the double-quotes with echo -e (for bash) and see if the command remains intact.  Where it does not, you need to add "\" to protect the characters in question, so that they will be passed on, as is to the remote server.  N.B.  be sure to understand Gordon Davisson's comments.

Comment: A heredoc with a quoted sigil (e.g. `'eof'`) to prevent variable expansion within the heredoc is often a useful way to feed ssh commands meant to be processed on the remote host. Many examples and answers already on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.  I wasn't aware the outer-most quoting will override any inner quoting but now that and Gordon Davisson's answer on the linked thread makes more sense to me.